# Pebble JS app_message_outbox_send() in a for loop

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am using sdk2 for pebble, with the js appmessage features:

I am trying to send consecutive messages to pebble js on the phone, for each one of my menu items.  A variable movie_count = 5 exists, and I use this for looping, It gets logged out as 5 as the code shows below, so it should be getting to all 5 , logging errors at least, but it just doesn't log anything after the first time:

```
static void up_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
 int i;
 APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "movie_count int %u", movie_count);
 for(i = 0;i<movie_count;i++){
    Tuplet build_menu_tuple =  TupletInteger(BUILD_MENU_KEY, 1); // just a flag for the  appmessage js code
    Tuplet menu_id_tuple =  TupletInteger(MENU_ID_KEY, i);
    DictionaryIterator *iter;
    app_message_outbox_begin(&iter);
    if (iter == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    dict_write_tuplet(iter, &build_menu_tuple);
    dict_write_tuplet(iter, &menu_id_tuple);
    dict_write_end(iter);
    app_message_outbox_send();
}
}
```

#### in JS appmessage

this code in the js is executed, although only once, I have logged the output in my `in_receiver()` callback in my watchapp, and my first item gets logged, but the logger just quits after that... Is this because the watchapp cannnot send blutooth messages in a loop like this? Is there a way to make sure the message is sent, or pause the execution so it sends at a slower pace? (the movies_json exists above the code below, i left it out for brevity, but it is there, a json object with an inner array of movies)

```
if(e.payload.build_menu){

            var menu_id = e.payload.menu_id;

            console.log("menu_id" + menu_id);

            Pebble.sendAppMessage({"title":movies_json.movies[menu_id].title,

                                   "stars":movies_json.movies[menu_id].stars,

                                   "menu_id":menu_id

            });

            console.log("movie title:" + movies_json.movies[i].title);

        }
```

#### in_recived_handler callback code to handle messages from the js

this code is in the callback that takes in messsages from the phones js... it only gets to the first item, logs just the first item's menu_id and title, and then logging just stops.

```
if(menu_id_tuple){
  int menu_id;
  menu_id = menu_id_tuple->value->int32;
  char movie_title[30];
  strncpy(movie_title, movie_title_tuple->value->cstring, 30);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "In received handler movie_title: %s" , movie_title);
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "In received handler menu_id: %u" , menu_id);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the first message is sent to send the next one.

The proper way to do this is to register a callback for the `outbox_sent` event and to queue the next message in this event.

### Explanation

There is only one bluetooth buffer on pebble and it can only hold one message at a time. If you send messages in a for loop, this buffer gets filled with the first message and all the other messages are rejected.

You would see the error messages if you checked the return value of `app_message_outbox_send()`. You should also implement a `AppMessageOutboxFailed` handler.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I am trying to display the error message like you state above:AppMessageResult err_app_send = app_message_outbox_send();
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "err app send %u", err_app_send); Am I on the right path, I am confused on how to get the error codes inside of AppMessageResult. When I run the code above in the for loop, it prints out 'err arr send 0' Does that correspond to the first error msg code , 'APP_MSG_OK' , within AppMessageResult? I was expecting it to print out the error code many times, but again, it stopped after once. I am still trying debug. thanks a lot!

Comment: 0 means the first message was queued properly. I think the second time you call it app_message_outbox_begin returns APP_MSG_BUSY and sets iter to NULL. This will send you into your return statement and that's why you do not see more error messages.

Comment: You just keep on saving my day! I blindly copied that from quotes.c in the Examples, thats what I get for pasting. I guess that code  was just a sanity check to see if there was something in iter, I wonder what the original intention for that code was.

Comment: You need to check the return value of the function - or the value of iter (this is what the example is doing). If you don't, you will try to access a pointer whose value is NULL and your program would crash.